# Checking data of all same class elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need the code to check the data-name value of all instances of .account-select.  Right now it just checks the first .account-select element and not any subsequent ones.

The function right now is on click of an element such as John Smith, it checks the data-name of the .account-select lis.  If the data-names are the same, it does not create a new li with the John Smith data.
If no data-names are equal to John Smith, then it adds an li with John Smith.

This is the JS-Fiddle I made for it so you can see what I am referring to: http://jsfiddle.net/rsxavior/vDCNy/22/
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

This is the Jquery Code I am using right now.

```
$('.account').click(function () {
   var acc = $(this).data("name");
    var sel = $('.account-select').data("name");           
    if (acc === sel) {
    }
    else {
         $('.account-hidden-li').append('<li class="account-select" data-name="'+ $(this).data("name") +'">' + $(this).data("name") + '<a class="close bcn-close" data-dismiss="alert" href="#">&times;</a></li>');
    }
});
```

And the HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li><a class="account" data-name="All" href="#">All</a></li>
    <li><a class="account" data-name="John Smith" href="#">John Smith</a></li>
</ul>

<ul class="account-hidden-li">
    <ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) to iterate over them all:

```
var acc = $(this).data('name');
$('.account-select').each(function(){
  var sel = $(this).data('name');
  if (acc == sel){
  }else{
    // $(...).append(...)
  }
});
```

Or you can use the [attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/):

```
$('.account-select[data-name="'+acc+'"]') // assuming no `"` in acc otherwise
                                          // you're going to need to escape it
```

Which means you can also use the [`:not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) selector to achieve what you're after:

```
var acc = $(this).data('name');
$('.account-select:not([data-name="'+acc+'"])')
  .append(...)
```

[Primitive Example](http://jsfiddle.net/mqk6c/)

Comment: Forgive me if I don't quite understand but I have added that into my click function.  Its important that it only triggers an action when the .account is clicked.  When clicking nothing seems to work.  Maybe I am placing it in the wrong format for it to be able to work.

Comment: `code`$('.account').click(function() {
    var acc= $(this).data('name');
$('.account-select').each(function(){
  var sel = $(this).data('name');
  if (acc == sel){
      //do nothing
  }else{
    $('.account-hidden-li').append('<li class="account-select" data-name="'+ $(this).data("name") +'">' + $(this).data("name") + '<a class="close bcn-close" data-dismiss="alert" href="#">&times;</a></li>');    
  }
});
   }); `code`

Comment: @Tiffani: Please explain what you're trying to accomplish and I'll do my best to answer the original problem at hand. And your jsFiddle example doesn't have any elements matching `.account-select`, so where is that originating from?

Comment: .account-select is generated through the .append function.  When someone clicks on an .account link, the Jquery grabs the data-name information and generates an li class of .account-select.
  What I am trying to do with the .account-select is when .account is clicked, it compares the data-name value to the data-name values of all of the .account-select elements present. If

Comment: they are the same, then the function does nothing, if they are different it will create that .select-account with the data-name from the .account that was clicked. It basically a filter and this 
  bit of code is to prevent people from selecting the same person twice.

Comment: That works perfectly!  Just for my future reference and so I can learn why does .size() work for matching in this case.  I thought it was only for property length? Thanks in advance!  I am trying to learn as much about JQuery and Javascript as I can.

Comment: i used `.size()` to see how many matches the selector found (i.e `$('div').size()` would tell me how many `<div>`s are on the page). So using a simple selector combined with `.size()` I was able to determine if an `.account-select` with that data attribute applied already exists.

Answer (score 1):

As you realized, `$('.account-select').data("name")` only gets the data from the 1st element.  You need to loop through each `.account-select` and get its data.

```
$('.account-select').each(function(i, v){
    var sel = $(v).data('name');
    if (acc === sel) {
        // Do something if they match
    }
    else{
        // Do something else if they don't
    }
});
```